# custom fields in hook_civicrm_pre' $params have an extra "_-1" suffix

Tags: custom-fields, hooks, core

On my latest Civi 5.37.2 the params array passed to `hook_civicrm_pre` looks like:

```
Array
(
    [hidden_custom] => 1
    [hidden_custom_group_count] => Array
        (
            [] => 1
        )
    [custom_395_-1] =>          <-------- Spooky appdx
    [custom_463_-1] => 1000     <-------- Spooky appdx
 [...]
```

This happens when adding a new activity to a case. `hook_civicrm_customPre` works in other cases but it is *not* fired here. So it seems, there is no hook to get a sane `custom_<fieldid>` param prior saving to db.

Comment: I think it's always been like this? And for editing an existing one it's not `-1` it's the autoincrement id in the customvalue table.

Comment: Jesus, I should have derived this from my dotnet and other orms development experience. Will you answer?

Comment: He he I thought this was a unique civi thing - maybe not.

Comment: No, using negative temporary ids is quite common, I think. Thanks a load!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted comment to answer:

I think it's always been like this? And for editing an existing one it's not -1 it's the autoincrement id in the customvalue table.